# how can a Calender list be used to approve the scheduling of a conference room?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

Looking to manage 3 separate conference rooms to be restricted to a small group of users (15-20 persons) and to be controlled by 2 different Admins.  Users to see the calendar of the CR availability, request to book a room thru the site which notifies the Admins and they can then approve or reject.  Upon approval the requester is notified and can add to their calendar and invite others.  If rejected, the requester is notified and the room can be booked by another user.